# I get an error because I can't instantiate an object inside another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I looked for an answer for my issue in this site but I couldn't find anything.

My earlier post was very long, so i'll try to improve it.

I have this model:

```
public class Product : EntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //attribuitions
        ....
        //Url das images?

        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
        //More attribuitions
        ....
}
```

My need is to load a property from mode but this property is a virtual property and i'm not geting to instantiate in my lambda. I did

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,            
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)

            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,

                DolarRate = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceUSD = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceUSD = 0.0m,

                CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
                PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
                Description = final.Product.Description,
                ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
                Name = final.Product.Name,
                NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
                PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
                Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
                Order = final.Product.Order,
                HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
                MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
                HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
                MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
                AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
                AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
                StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup,
                DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
                PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName

            }).ToList();

            qry.ForEach(q =>
            {                
                var product = new Product();

                product.CategoryId = q.CategoryId;
                product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                product.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                product.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                product.Hidden = q.Hidden;
                product.ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId;
                product.Description = q.Description;
                product.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                product.MaximumPercentage = q.MaximumPercentage;
                product.MinimumPercentage = q.MinimumPercentage;
                product.Name = q.Name;
                product.NameHtml = q.NameHtml;
                product.Order = q.Order;
                product.PartNumber = q.PartNumber;
                product.PictureId = q.PictureId;
                product.ShortDescription = q.ShortDescription;
                product.StandardMarkup = q.StandardMarkup;

                var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                q.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

               //if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
                    //q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;

                var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

            });
```

But when i run the code above in the commented lines i get an exception of NullReference. It's happening due Picture i can not instantiate it. I did a left join below `.Where(First query)` and nothing. I tried to put `.Include` this way: `_productRepository.Table.Include(pic => pic.Picture).GroupJoin` and nothing. I tried `.Include` after `.Where` and nothing. In other words, i did many attempts and i didn't get. I tried a anonymous e nothing. What do i do? What wrong am I doing?

**EDIT1**

If i put `.Include` like this

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.Include(pic => pic.Picture).GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)

            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,
                ................... //Attribuitions below
```

I think that i don't need `new Product()` inside qry.ForEach, correct? Then how do i do, do i need to do a `new Product()`? Putting an `include` i don't know what to do or how.

Comment: The problem is when i did a new Picture this killed CatalogItemResponse, i think. Maybe if i do a  new anounimous it can solve my issue, correct?

Comment: In my Left Join, if i make this: .`Select(sel => new
            {
                FileName = sel.Product.Picture.FileName
            })` i get an error in this line `.Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)`this is the error: **Anonymous string: FileName doesn't contains a definition to Product**.....

Comment: You do `var product = new Product()`, so `product` is not a lazy-loading proxy.

Comment: @GertArnold i understood what you said above. `product` need to be a lazy loading proxy, correct? And how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are setting the `Picture` in your `ForEach`. Although the problem is most likely a result of you not including the `Picture` entity in your query for `Product`. Try adding it to the `GroupJoin` on the condition that `Picture.Id == Product.PictureId`.

You could also use the more convenient `.Include` to `eager load` the `Picture` entity.

Comment: eager load is opposite of lazy load, correct? Because is very slow retrieve data from web service(asmx), 4 or 6 min to retrieve 202 records

Comment: Yes, eager loading is opposite of lazy loading. Lazy loading can be very expensive if  the data been lazy loaded is large and loaded separately. If the data is separate, it will take several round trips to load the required data.

Comment: Personally, I always create separate methods for loading required data. I don't load what I don't need at a time that I'm certain I don't need it. I keep requests as atomic as possible. So I don't need to rely on lazy loading to query for me when I need it. That way, I'm sure no major performance hits will result from unexpected lazy loading.

Comment: I'm having difficult to put another object(table) in the lambda above. How can i do to insert another table in that lambda(`var qry = ...`)? I tried before **Where clause** but it doesn't work. All difficult is due ***Picture*** inside ***Product***. Any help is welcome. I am not asking for code ready but how to do

Comment: staa99, i'm sorry, how can i put Picture in the join? How can i do this? I'm having great difficult to understand what you said